# On Excess onDemand(EOD) spyder application comes up with black display

Tags: python, linux, pyqt, spyder

Platform: Excess onDemand (EoD) with Red hat version6.10
Here I have launched spyder3 application and spyder3 comes up with black display.
I even can not see its toolbar.
I suspect this is pyqt problem and but dont know how to debug it below are details

```
Python 3.6.4 (default, Jan 31 2018, 22:47:26) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux
>>> >>> >>> PYQT_VERSION = 329473
PYQT_VERSION_STR = 5.7.1
QOpenGLVersionProfile = <class 'PyQt5.QtGui.QOpenGLVersionProfile'>
QT_VERSION = 329473
QT_VERSION_STR = 5.7.1
```

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Are you trying to use Spyder through SSH?

Comment: No ..Actually our IT team has made setup for EOD with RHEL6 machine.

Comment: This is a problem with your graphics card drivers. If you're using Nvidia cards, you should try to update their drivers or switch to use your Intel card.